# Most efficient way to add a method in ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is the most CPU efficient way to add a method to an object?

This is what I have now,

```
@pmacio.define_method(:waitfor) do |*args|
  c = @pmacio.read(1)
  until args[0] =~ c do
    c = @pmacio.read(1)
  end 
end
```

called like:

```
@pmacio.waitfor(/\cF|\cG/)
```

But there are other ways: `define_singleton_method` etc. This method is called in the idle loop of a GNOME 2.0 based app and it needs to be as CPU efficient as possible.

EDIT: the accepted answer would look like:

```
def @pmacio.waitfor(c)
  ....
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question looks like it could be interesting, but at the moment I'd suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it to 1) remove unnecessary "storytelling" and 2) explain what exactly the `waitfor` method should be doing ...maybe link to the documentation of the telnet method.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does it mean to "add a method to an instance variable"? You can only add methods to modules. An instance variable is not a module. An instance variable is not even an object (variables aren't objects in Ruby).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code defines a method on the *value* of the instance variable `@pmacio`, not on the instance variable itself, which is not an object.

Suppose

```
h = { :a => 1 }
@pmacio = h
```

Then

```
def @pmacio.my_method
  "meow"
end
  #=> :my_method
```

so now

```
@pmacio.my_method
  #=> "meow"
```

but if we change the value of `@pmacio`:

```
@pmacio = "cat"
```

we find

```
@pmacio.my_method
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `my_method' for "cat":String
```

That is because you have defined a method on `h`:

```
h.my_method
  #=> "meow"
```

You might as well write

```
def h.my_method
  "meow"
end
```

in the first place, and then execute

```
@pmacio = h
```

The upshot is that this question has nothing to do with instance variables.

Note you cannot define methods on certain objects:

```
def 1.my_method
end
  #=> #SyntaxError: (irb):861: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad use of lingo,  Can I assume the much easier syntax is also going to be more CPU efficient?

Comment: I would be surprised if the way you define the method has any effect on efficiency.